# Oracle SQL: Simplify multiple select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I need to do a COUNT for each month in a year so I do this:

```
SELECT 
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '01' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS jan,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '02' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS fev,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '03' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS mar,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '04' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS abr,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '05' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS mai,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '06' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS jun,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '07' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS jul,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '08' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS ago,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '09' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS stb,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '10' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS out,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '11' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS nov,
(
    SELECT  COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
    to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '12' AND
    {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
) AS dez

FROM dual
```

Is there a way to simplify this?
Cheers.

Comment: This isn't native Oracle SQL. Is it run through a sort of preprocessor before executing it?

Comment: It's definitely not a valid SQL statement at all. The use of the non-standard `[]` "quotes" seem to indicate that this is actually a SQL Server statement. But the usage of the `{}` is not possible in any DBMS I know

Comment: Yes..this isn't standard SQL... Between {} we have table name, between [] attributes and @xxx its variables. Before querying the BD the statement is pre-processed to actually use real names.

Comment: Interestingly, nobody has proposed a PIVOT query. This would be a prime application for it.

Comment: @Codo: Oracle (at least up to 10g) doesn't include a PIVOT clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '01' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS jan,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '02' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS fev,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '03' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS mar,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '04' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS abr,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '05' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS mai,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '06' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS jun,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '07' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS jul,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '08' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS ago,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '09' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS stb,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '10' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS out,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '11' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS nov,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM') = '12' 
                  THEN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) END) AS dez
FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
{PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
```

Includes a fairly generic method of pivoting the results. Note that since there is no restriction on year, data from multiple years could be appearing in each month's results - this would also be true of the original query.

Comment: Actually I will need to restrict the year... I just have to add it in the WHERE clause right?

Comment: @JoaoHeleno: Yes, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pivot operation. In 11G:

[sample](http://orafaq.com/wiki/PIVOT):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT job, deptno, sum(sal) sal FROM emp GROUP BY job, deptno)
         PIVOT ( sum(sal) FOR deptno IN (10, 20, 30, 40) );

JOB               10         20         30         40
--------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
CLERK           1300       1900        950
SALESMAN                              5600
PRESIDENT       5000
MANAGER         2450       2975       2850
ANALYST
```

with your code:

```
SELECT  * 
  FROM 
    ( SELECT 
      COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} 
       ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} 
       on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE 
      {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
      {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
    PIVOT ( COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]) 
            FOR to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MON') IN
              ('JAN','FEB','MAR', ..., 'DEC')
    )
```

For previous version, sample:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  (SELECT job,
                sum(decode(deptno,10,sal)) DEPT10,
                sum(decode(deptno,20,sal)) DEPT20,
                sum(decode(deptno,30,sal)) DEPT30,
                sum(decode(deptno,40,sal)) DEPT40
           FROM scott.emp
       GROUP BY job)
ORDER BY 1;
```

for your code:

```
SELECT  * 
  FROM 
    ( SELECT 
        COUNT( decode( to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MON'), 
                       'JAN',
                       {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]
                      )
              ) JAN,
        COUNT( decode( to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MON'), 
                       'FEB',
                       {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]
                      )
              ) FEB,
        ...
        COUNT( decode( to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MON'), 
                       'DEC',
                       {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade]
                      )
              ) DEC,
    FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
    INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} 
       ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
    INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} 
       on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
    WHERE 
      {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
      {PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
    )
```

disclaimer: not tested. Check for month short names in your language.

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table with the needed values (month and quantity).

```
SELECT to_char({ENCOMENDA}.[DataSubmissao], 'MM'), COUNT( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[Quantidade])
FROM (( {ENCOMENDA}
INNER JOIN {ENCOMENDA_LINHA} ON ( {ENCOMENDA}.[Id] = {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[EncomendaId] ))
INNER JOIN {PRODUTO} on ( {ENCOMENDA_LINHA}.[ProdutoId] = {PRODUTO}.[Id] ))
WHERE {ENCOMENDA}.[EstadoId] = @EstadoEncomenda AND
{PRODUTO}.[ProdutoTipoId] = @TipoProduto
```

And afterwords select what you need from it.

Comment: You'll need a `GROUP BY` for this approach.

Comment: Could I use dual for this effect? Could I insert values 1 to 12 into dual? How would the query be using this approach?